# Angular/PrimeNG - regex keyFilter with additional restriction of input values

Tags: angular, regex, primeng, ip-address, keyevent

I want to create a [keyFilter](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/keyfilter) to verify an IP address using [IP-regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5284147/validating-ipv4-addresses-with-regexp) as follows:

```
<input pInputText type="text" [(ngModel)]="value1" [pKeyFilter]= "IPAddressKeyFilter" [pValidateOnly]="true" placeholder="0.0.0.0"/>
```

The IP verification itself works good but it's still possible to **enter any other character** except of "[0-9.]"

This is due to **pValidateOnly** set to true. Otherwise every single key stroke is compared to the IP-regex which will fail (refer to [post#1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62478105/18578004) or [post#2](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/5331#issuecomment-388217069)).

---

### how to block any input except "[0-9.]"?

Some combination of [inputMask](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/inputmask) and keyFilter/regex would be fine. But the inputMask does not work at all for this use case.

**Refer to this example @ [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-a94aqp-8kpge8?file=src/app/app.component.html) to get a better understanding of the situation.**

---

## UPDATE

I implemented some **events** (thanks to [@Morfioss](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72204793/18578004)).

I've updated the **stackblitz** from above.

### Summary:

- Added **Paste**-event which was not possible via keyFilter (processes also the IP-regex)
- Implemented **KeyDown**-event to check if entered key is "[0-9.]".
- Fixed prior Paste-event because "CTRL+V" was also **blocked** via KeyDown-event ("Backspace", "Del" or any navigation with Arrow-Keys as well => bypassed these cases within the event manually...)

So, this is how it's basically implemented so far:

```js
// component.ts
export class AppComponent {
  IPv4AddressKeyFilter: RegExp =
    /(^\s*((([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]))\s*$)/;

  IPAddressInputOnly: RegExp = new RegExp('[0-9.]');

  valueIPv4: string = '';

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {}
  
  OnIPAddressPaste(event: ClipboardEvent) {
    let clipboardData = event.clipboardData;
    let pastedText = clipboardData.getData('text');

    if (this.IPv4AddressKeyFilter.test(pastedText)) {
      this.valueIPv4 = pastedText;
      return true;
    }

    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }

  OnIPAddressKeyDown(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    switch (event.key) {
      case 'Backspace':
      case 'Delete':
      case 'ArrowLeft':
      case 'ArrowRight':
      case 'Home':
      case 'End':
        return true;
    }

    if (event.ctrlKey) {
      switch (event.key) {
        case 'c':
        case 'v':
        case 'x':
          return true;
      }
    }

    if (this.IPAddressInputOnly.test(event.key)) {
      return true;
    }
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- component.html -->
<input
    pInputText
    type="text"
    [(ngModel)]="valueIPv4"
    [pKeyFilter]="IPv4AddressKeyFilter"
    [pValidateOnly]="true"
    placeholder="0.0.0.0"
    (paste)="OnIPAddressPaste($event)"
    (keydown)="OnIPAddressKeyDown($event)"
  />
```

Btw. the **KeyPress**-event would just work fine unlike the KeyDown... Yet it's deprecated (refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3396805/18578004))

I've also tried **Input**, **KeyUp**, **BeforeInput** events which not worked as expected... Not sure what's best-practice to use anyway.

Sample code for these is also provided in the **stackblitz** above.

***I'm not 100% satisfied with this solution but it works out for me so far. Would appreciate any comment, opinion or whatsoever.***

Answer (score 1):

all you need to do is to add an event in the input
:

```js
NumberOnly(e) {
    var regex = new RegExp("[0-9]");
    var str = String.fromCharCode(!e.charCode ? e.which : e.charCode);
    if (regex.test(str)) {
      return true;
    }
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }
  onPaste(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }
```

```html
html

<input (input)="NumberOnly($event)"/>
```

also try adding   type="number" in the input in HTML

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for the reply. It definitely lead me into the right direction. 

Using type="number" unfortunately does not work for IP address as I also need to enter multiple "." or later for IPv6 ":" and letters from "A" - "F".

Anyway, I ended up using the KeyUp event to filter before input. I will update my post and also the example.

Maybe someone has better ideas but for now I'm happy with the solution.